# mysql single quote in arithmatic functions

Tags: mysql, database, math, quote, arithmetic-expressions

In mysql, if I do something like

```
round((amount * '0.75'),2)
```

it seem to work just fine like without single quotes for 0.75. Is there a difference in how mysql process this?

Comment: No significant difference that I know of.

Comment: I was under the impression that putting a value within single quote will result in mysql considering it as a String/Varchar. But that doesn't seem to be the case. Any idea why?

Comment: It does consider it a string. But when you use an arithmetic operator on a string, it converts it to a number.

Comment: Thanks! Is it significantly inefficient or not something to worry about?

Comment: If it's a literal string in the SQL, I expect it will be converted at parse time so there's no overhead at all. If it's coming from a table column, there will be some conversion overhead. But I wonder why you would be storing numbers as strings in the table.

Comment: It's literal string in the SQL. Thanks @Barmar for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hope to close out this question, here's a link that explains type conversion in expression evaluation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to
>   strings as necessary, and vice versa.

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
        -> 2
```

In your case, MySQL sees arithmetic and performs implicit conversion on any string contained in the expression. There is going to be an overheard in converting a string to number, but it's negligible. My preference is to explicitly type out a number instead of quoting it. That method has helped me in code clarity and maintainability.